# Sorting a list based on the order of another list

Tags: python, list, sorting

I have the following list:

```
I=[1,4, 3, 7,8,9]
```

I have another two lists which are subsets of list `I`:

```
IU=[3,9]
IUU=[4,8]
```

I have to merge lists `IU` and `IUU`to create list `J` in such a way that the elements of the merged list follow the orders of the elements of list `I`.

```
J=[4,3,8,9]
```

I am looking for some ideas on how to implement this. If I just add the sublist I get following result.

```
J=IU+IUU
J=[3, 9, 4, 8]
```

I will appreciate your comments/answers.

Comment: Are there repeated elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just do something like:

```
sorted(IU + IUU, key={e:i for i,e in enumerate(I)}.get)
```

Which should be O(N*Log N)

The problem with `key=I.index` is that this will force your performance to deteriorate to O(N**2).

Comment: perfect thanks so much! this is more efficient for larger n

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. Thanks for looking.

```
sorted(J,key=I.index)
```

Comment: note, this will be O(N**2)